# How can I detect with javascript if an attribute "#" is appended to an url?

Tags: javascript

How can I detect with javascript if an attribute "#" is appended to an url ?

I need a cross-browser solution. I'm currently using the following code, but it works only in Firefox:

```
if ((window.location.hash) || (window.location.hash != "#"))
    window.scrollBy(0,-60);
```

thanks

Comment: In which browser does it fail? According to w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) `location.hash` should work in all major browsers.

Comment: @Martin Buberl So you are saying that theoretically I just need the first part of the if statement ? window.location.hash ?

Comment: I believe he's saying that your code should work in all browsers.

Comment: If you jst want to check if there is an appending hash, you could simply write: `if(!!window.location.hash)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line should do the job for you:

```
if(!!window.location.hash) // if 'true' you have an appending hash
     window.scrollBy(0,-60);
```

According to w3schools [`location.hash`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) should work in all major browsers.

Comment: The first `!` checks if the hash is undefined or empty. Which will return a `false` if there is an hash in the URL. This gets just negated with the second `!` to fit the logic. You could also write `if(!window.location.hash == false)`.

Answer (score 3):

First, there seems to be an error in your posted code. If you're going for the common `string is neither null nor empty nor '#'` pattern, it should be:

```
if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash != "#")
    window.scrollBy(0,-60);
```

That said, since [Location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Location_object) is well-supported, the code above should work on all modern browsers.

Comment: by the way, is window.scrollBy(0,-60); cross-browser ? The hash is no correctly detected in all browsers, but it doesn't scroll in the same way for all of them...

Comment: `scrollBy()` is also widely supported. The discrepancies between browsers might be because they render your page in quirks mode. What's your `DOCTYPE`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're finding that the hash property doesn't work in a key browser, you could always just do string parsing, a naive implementation might look like:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var hashLoc = url.lastIndexOf('#');
if(hashLoc > -1 && hashLoc < url.length )
     window.scrollBy(0,-60);
```

Answer (score 0):

For good cross-browser support you can turn to jQuery. It might be overkill for your project, but overall it makes js developing much easier. There is an excellent [hashchange](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) plugin which I have used with great success for a couple of months.